# problem with using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, junit, websphere

I am getting following error while executing a unti test case(JUNIT).I am using it to understand the part of the project.Project is a web based project.Project is using OPENJPA

```
<openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:523)
    at com.XYZ.cloud.admin.loadCatalog.LoadCatalogTest.populateOffering(LoadCatalogTest.java:253)
    at com.XYZ.cloud.admin.loadCatalog.LoadCatalogTest.CatalogUploadTest(LoadCatalogTest.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4231)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4196)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:503)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:64)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractJDBCSeq.next(AbstractJDBCSeq.java:65)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ImplHelper.generateValue(ImplHelper.java:160)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ImplHelper.generateFieldValue(ImplHelper.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.assignField(JDBCStoreManager.java:698)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ApplicationIds.assign(ApplicationIds.java:487)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ApplicationIds.assign(ApplicationIds.java:463)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.assignObjectId(JDBCStoreManager.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.assignObjectId(DelegatingStoreManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:519)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:2823)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PNewState.beforeFlush(PNewState.java:39)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:959)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1908)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1826)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1350)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:877)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:512)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.allocateSequence(TableJDBCSeq.java:419)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.nextInternal(TableJDBCSeq.java:290)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractJDBCSeq.next(AbstractJDBCSeq.java:60)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.doNonTransactionalWork(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:306)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.allocateSequence(TableJDBCSeq.java:415)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.InvalidStateException: Could not perform automatic lookup of EJB container's javax.transaction.TransactionManager implementation. Please ensure that you are running the application from within an EJB 1.1 compliant EJB container, and then set the org.apache.openjpa.ManagedRuntime property to  
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.getTransactionManager(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:250)
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.doNonTransactionalWork(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:304)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Name space accessor for the java: name space has not been set. Possible cause is that the user is specifying a java: URL name in a JNDI Context method call but is not running in a J2EE client or server environment.
    at com.XYZ.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.isNameSpaceAccessable(javaURLContextFactory.java:93)
    at com.XYZ.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextFactory.getObjectInstance(UrlContextFactory.java:82)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext(NamingManager.java:655)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:434)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:450)
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.RegistryManagedRuntime.getTransactionManager(RegistryManagedRuntime.java:61)
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.getTransactionManager(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:154)
    ... 48 more
```

Comment: Did you start transaction at all? EntityManager.getTransaction().begin()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to use a `persistence.xml` declaring a `jta-data-source` in a unit test context (i.e. in a Java SE context).

In other words, you're not using an appropriate `persistence.xml` for a testing context. You need a specific `persistence.xml` using a `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transaction type and configure it to use a built-in connection pool (instead of a datasource).

Show your `persistence.xml` if you need more guidance.

Comment: But i have one more problem ,I  use 2 separate database, so i have to use JTA to handle distributed databases.So  how can i test my code using JTA?

Comment: @akp This is somehow a different problem and I'm not going to cover it in a comment box. Open another question with the required details.

Comment: i have posted the questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952124/unit-testing-code-which-uses-jpa-jta

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message suggests: You need to make sure that you are running the application from within an EJB 1.1 compliant EJB container.

Comment: Thanks for replying:But i want to unit test the only this part of project, how can i do it?

Comment: I debugged the code and found that an exception is thrown when tx.commit() is called.I have pasted proper exception now.Can you plese suggent me some way by which i can run only this part of project?

Comment: Consider using a Mocking framework instead of connecting to a real DB or try DBUnit

Comment: Thanks again.But the my whole purpose is to understandt how data goes in which table.b

Comment: Can u  please suggest me by which i can run this unit test case under a EJB container, without using the entire project,I mean only the part of project am concerned with

Comment: After some googling I found this: http://knol.google.com/k/how-to-unit-test-enterprise-java-beans-ejb#

Comment: thanks a lot .Am goiing through that article.Will try it and get back to you

Comment: @jeroen.I dint understand much from that article.I dont have much experince.Can u plese help

Answer (score 0):

I wasted nearly an hour o fix this. The issue was very basic. The @Id and @GeneratedValue was not annotated on the id field.
As we are using *JPA Tools* in RAD, Eclipse to generate the entity classes, it does not annotate id field.
So, this can be fixed by placing the @Id field.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.Identity)
@Column(name="some_name")
private long someNameId;
```