# unit testing code which uses JPA & JTA

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, ejb-3.0, jta

I use 2 separate database, so i have to use JTA to handle distributed transactions.So either  either both db have to commit or both rollback. I use open JPA and JTA.Now to unit test the code  using junit  ? I get the following error when i try to run my code which handles distributed transcations.I had posted similar question on this site and someone asked me to refer
http://knol.google.com/k/how-to-unit-test-enterprise-java-beans-ejb# 
But i dint understand any thing from there.

```
<openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:523)
    at com.XYZ.cloud.admin.loadCatalog.LoadCatalogTest.populateOffering(LoadCatalogTest.java:253)
    at com.XYZ.cloud.admin.loadCatalog.LoadCatalogTest.CatalogUploadTest(LoadCatalogTest.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4231)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4196)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:503)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:64)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractJDBCSeq.next(AbstractJDBCSeq.java:65)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ImplHelper.generateValue(ImplHelper.java:160)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ImplHelper.generateFieldValue(ImplHelper.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.assignField(JDBCStoreManager.java:698)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ApplicationIds.assign(ApplicationIds.java:487)
    at org.apache.openjpa.util.ApplicationIds.assign(ApplicationIds.java:463)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.assignObjectId(JDBCStoreManager.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.assignObjectId(DelegatingStoreManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:519)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:2823)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PNewState.beforeFlush(PNewState.java:39)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:959)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1908)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1826)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1350)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:877)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:512)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.allocateSequence(TableJDBCSeq.java:419)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.nextInternal(TableJDBCSeq.java:290)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractJDBCSeq.next(AbstractJDBCSeq.java:60)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: Unable to obtain a TransactionManager using null. 
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.doNonTransactionalWork(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:306)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.TableJDBCSeq.allocateSequence(TableJDBCSeq.java:415)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.InvalidStateException: Could not perform automatic lookup of EJB container's javax.transaction.TransactionManager implementation. Please ensure that you are running the application from within an EJB 1.1 compliant EJB container, and then set the org.apache.openjpa.ManagedRuntime property to  
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.getTransactionManager(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:250)
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.doNonTransactionalWork(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:304)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Name space accessor for the java: name space has not been set. Possible cause is that the user is specifying a java: URL name in a JNDI Context method call but is not running in a J2EE client or server environment.
    at com.XYZ.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.isNameSpaceAccessable(javaURLContextFactory.java:93)
    at com.XYZ.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextFactory.getObjectInstance(UrlContextFactory.java:82)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext(NamingManager.java:655)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:434)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:450)
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.RegistryManagedRuntime.getTransactionManager(RegistryManagedRuntime.java:61)
    at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.getTransactionManager(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:154)
    ... 48 more
```

Answer (score 2):

> I use 2 separate database, so I have to use JTA to handle distributed transactions. So either either both db have to commit or both rollback. I use open JPA and JTA.Now to unit test the code using junit?

If you want to run integration tests outside the container and use JTA, you'll have to

1. setup a standalone JTA transaction manager like [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/), [Bitronix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Home), etc (I'd pick Atomikos for its documentation)
2. setup JTA capable datasource(s)
3. wrap the whole thing together.

I warmly suggest to use Spring and to have a look [Spring, JPA, and JTA with Hibernate and JOTM](http://erich.soomsam.net/2007/04/24/spring-jpa-and-jta-with-hibernate-and-jotm/) (but adapt it to use Atomikos, Bitronix).

#### Resources

- [Atomikos TransactionsEssentials](http://www.atomikos.com/Main/TransactionsEssentials)

#### Related questions

- [Atomikos vs JOTM vs Bitronix vs ????](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978207/atomikos-vs-jotm-vs-bitronix-vs)
- [How to obtain JNDI data source for JPA/JTA DAO integration test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008486/how-to-obtain-jndi-data-source-for-jpa-jta-dao-integration-test)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use OpenEjb for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Wicket application with EJB 3. Production works on Glassfish 2 (Toplink - JPA 1). Unit tests work on OpenEJB 3. I needed OpenEJB in unit tests to use awesome Wicket integration tests.

I assume you have a Maven project. If not, grab the dependencies manually.

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <!-- It's provided by Glassfish but while testing OpenEJB needs it explicitly -->
    <groupId>toplink.essentials</groupId>
    <artifactId>toplink-essentials</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-58g</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <!-- not sure about this one but probably it's needed -->
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.13</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you put it just after `<dependencies>`.

AbstactOpenEjbTest class:

```
public abstract class AbstractOpenEjbTest {

    private static final String JTA_DATA_SOURCE = "jdbc/SeobserwatorDS";

    protected static InitialContext context;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createInitialContext() throws Exception {
        setSystemProperties();

        final Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty(JTA_DATA_SOURCE, "new://Resource?type=DataSource");
        properties.setProperty(JTA_DATA_SOURCE + ".JdbcDriver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.setProperty(JTA_DATA_SOURCE + ".JdbcUrl", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inne_test");
        properties.setProperty(JTA_DATA_SOURCE + ".UserName", "xxx");
        properties.setProperty(JTA_DATA_SOURCE + ".Password", "yyy");

        context = new InitialContext(properties);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setSystemProperties() {
        System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
        System.setProperty("toplink.target-server", "net.nowaker.nhr.seobserwator.web.OpenEjbTransactionController");
        System.setProperty("toplink.ddl-generation", "drop-and-create-tables");
        System.setProperty("toplink.logging.level", "WARNING");
        System.setProperty("toplink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "both");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractOpenEjbTest() {
        // Execute manually all ServletContextListeners as we are outside the container
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void removeTables() throws Exception {
        // some clean-up, e.g. delete all data
    }
}
```

Some weird class I can't recall what it was for but is needed:

```
import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;
import oracle.toplink.essentials.transaction.JTATransactionController;

/**
 * Transaction controller for OpenEJB standalone/embedded and Toplink
 *
 * @see http://qbeukes.blogspot.com/2008/08/toplink-as-your-openejb-persistence.html
 */
public class OpenEjbTransactionController extends JTATransactionController {

    public static final String JNDI_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_NAME = "java:comp/TransactionManager";

    public OpenEjbTransactionController() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected TransactionManager acquireTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return (TransactionManager) jndiLookup(JNDI_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_NAME);
    }
}
```

Example test:

```
public class OpenEjbTest extends AbstractOpenEjbTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldAddUserWithStatelessBean() throws Exception {
        // when
        final AuthServiceLocal authService = EjbUtils.lookupBean(AuthServiceLocal.class);
        final CrudServiceLocal crudService = EjbUtils.lookupBean(CrudServiceLocal.class);

        // then
        assertFalse(authService.userExists("nonExistent"));
        final User unmanagedUser = new User(null, "a", "b", "c", "d", 12345678, new Date());
        final User managedUser = crudService.update(unmanagedUser);
        assertNotNull(managedUser.getId());
        assertNotNull(crudService.find(User.class, managedUser.getId()));
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.